# plotting multiple plots in ggplot2 on same graph that are unrelated

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline, smoothing

How would one use the `smooth.spline()` method in a `ggplot2` scatterplot?

If my data is in the data frame called data, with two columns, `x` and `y`.

The `smooth.spline` would be `sm <- smooth.spline(data$x, data$y)`. I believe I should use `geom_line()`, with `sm$x` and `sm$y` as the `xy` coordinates. However, how would one plot a scatterplot and a lineplot on the same graph that are completely unrelated? I suspect it has something to do with the `aes()` but I am getting a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different data(frames) in different geoms and call the relevant variables using aes or you could combine the relevant variables from the output of smooth.spline

```
# example data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20, 10,2))
dat$y <- dat$x^2 - 20*dat$x + rnorm(20,10,2)

# spline
s <- smooth.spline(dat)

# plot - combine the original x & y and the fitted values returned by 
# smooth.spline into a data.frame

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x=s$data$x, y=s$data$y, xfit=s$x, yfit=s$y)) +
                      geom_point(aes(x,y)) + geom_line(aes(xfit, yfit))

# or you could use geom_smooth    
ggplot(dat, aes(x , y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Cannot one supply the `smooth.spline` function to the `method` argument?

Comment: I don't know - do you mean like `geom_smooth(method="smooth.spline")` - i just tried it and it didn't work. [This old Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/FJ36CJH-ODo) suggests writing a wrapper.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I was using `ggplot(aes())` when I should have avoided `aes()` statements in `ggplot()` completely and instead done `aes()` in each of `geom_point()` and `geom_line()` separately.